# Flatpickr mobile format

Tags: javascript, datepicker, flatpickr

i am using ember-flatpickr version 2.12.0 and I am facing a formatting issue on mobile devices. I set the property dateFormat to "d.m.Y" which works fine on desktop browsers, but on mobiles formates to "mm/dd/yyyy". Can somebody help me with this?
[check out the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLoNy.png)

- flatpickr version used: 4.5.4

Here is     [repro link](https://jsfiddle.net/of62rjw7/), just switch your browser to responsive mode or check it on mobile.
Thank you for advices

```js
const fp = flatpickr(".date", {
 dateFormat: 'd.m.Y'
});
```

```css
article {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr@4.5.5/dist/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr@4.5.5/dist/flatpickr.js"></script>
<article>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." class=date>
</article>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I am facing the same problem in my mobile view.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who are facing the same problem, you can disable the mobile view option.

Add the following option in flatpickr:

```
{
    disableMobile: "true"
}
```

For more information, [Mobile Support - FlatPickr Documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/mobile-support/)